# Show that there is odd number of elements of a finite group satisfying $x^3=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that:
Show that there is odd number of elements of a finite group satisfying $x^3=e $? And even number of elements satisfying $x^2\neq e$???

I donot have any idea how to start.

Comment: The claim is false as can be seen by considering the group of order $3$.

Comment: Do you mean "the number of elements such that $g^3=e$"?  (that's different, as it includes the identity)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "order"? Most people when referring to "order of a group $G$ refer to the size/cardinality. of the set $|G|$.

Comment: Hint:  if $x,y$ are two such elements ($\neq e$) then the two sets $\{e,x,x^2\}$ and $\{e,y,y^2\}$ either coincide or intersect only at $e$.

Comment: I have edited the question/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $M = \{x \in G-\{e\}, x^3=e\}$. It is easy to show that if $x \in M$ then $x^{-1} \in M$, because $x^{-1}=x^2$. Since $M=\bigcup \{x, x^{-1}\}$ where the sets $\{x, x^{-1}\}$ are disjoint, we deduce $M$ has an even number of elements. It is important to notice that if $x \in M$ then $x^{-1} \ne x$, otherwise $x=x^{-1}$ implies $x=x^2$, then $x=e$.

For the second part, let $P=\{ x \in G, x^2 \ne e \}$. If $x \in P$ then $x^{-1} \in P$, otherwise $x^2 = e$. Then $P=\bigcup \{x, x^{-1}\}$ where the sets $\{x, x^{-1}\}$ are disjoint, so $P$ has an even number of elements.

Comment: Apparently, "$3$" can be replaced with any odd number

Answer (score 8):

There is an involution on the set of all elements $g$ such that $g^3=e$ sending $g$ to $g^{-1}$.  This involution has exactly one fixed point, namely $g=e$.  Hence altogether there is an odd number of them.

Comment: This answer is beyond my level and thinking.

Comment: Look at it this way: if you have an innumerable number of pairs of ears, and in addition a nose, then altogether you will necessarily have an odd number of organs.

Comment: The nose is the neutral element (read "Perfume: The Story of a Murderer", of Patrick Süskind).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Is there anything in the proposition that requires finiteness of group ?

Comment: No, only the finiteness of the number of elements $g$ satisfying $g^3=e$. @viru